# C++ primer 5th ed. function template overloading

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction, function-templates-overloading

In the book *C++ Primer*, there is an example about function template overloading:

> ```
> // print any type we don't otherwise handle
> template <typename T> string debug_rep(const T &t)
> {
>     cout << "debug_rep(T const&)\n";
>     ostringstream ret; // see § 8.3 (p. 321)
>     ret << t; // uses T's output operator to print a representation of t
>     return ret.str(); // return a copy of the string to which ret is bound
> }
>
> // print pointers as their pointer value, followed by the object to which the pointer points
> // NB: this function will not work properly with char*; see § 16.3 (p. 698)
> template <typename T> string debug_rep(T *p)
> {
>     std::cout << "debug_rep(T*)\n";
>     ostringstream ret;
>     ret << "pointer: " << p << '\n';         // print the pointer's own value
>     if (p)
>         ret << " " << debug_rep(*p); // print the value to which p points
>     else
>         ret << " null pointer";      // or indicate that the p is null
>     return ret.str(); // return a copy of the string to which ret is bound
> }
> ```
>
> If we call debug_rep with a pointer:
>
> ```
> cout << debug_rep(&s) << endl;
> ```
>
> both functions generate viable instantiations:
>
> - `debug_rep(const string* &)`, which is the instantiation of the first version of debug_rep with `T` bound to `string*`
> - `debug_rep(string*)`, which is the instantiation of the second version of `debug_rep` with `T` bound to `string*`
>
> The instantiation of the second version of `debug_rep` is an exact match for this call.
>
> The instantiation of the first version requires a conversion of the plain pointer to a pointer to `const`. Normal function matching says we should prefer the second template, and indeed that is the one that is run.

But if I declare the pointer to string as `const` although there's no conversion the second version is always chosen:

```
    string const s("hi"); // const
    cout << debug_rep(&s) << '\n';
```

So I think it is a mistake in the book and I think because the version takes a pointer is preferred because we pass a pointer being `const` or not (`T` will be deduced as `std::string const*` or `std::string*`).

What do you think?

Comment: Which edition of C++ Primer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book is wrong.

In the first example, the instantiation generated is not `debug_rep(const string* &)`, it is `debug_rep(string* const&)`. That is, `const` qualifies the pointer, not the thing pointed to. (This would be more obvious if the book used right const; that is, `template <typename T> string debug_rep(T const& t)` for the first function template.)

Indeed, `T` and `T const&` have equal priority as function template overloads; where they form an overload set it will be ambiguous. The reason `T*` is chosen over `T const&` is that it is *more specialized*; simply put, an arbitrary `T*` can be passed to a function taking `T const&`, while an arbitrary `T const&` cannot be passed to a function taking `T*`.

Comment: This kind of explains my problem: https://godbolt.org/z/T43q34. Does it mean that the _more-specialized_ concept is involved in overload resolution? (I would expect that both instances are instantiated and then the overload resolution applies, but this would result in ambiguity.)

Comment: @DanielLangr sure! if a function template is overloaded and there's no non-template viable fumction but only template versions which are equally good matches then the more specialized one is selected by function matching otherwise the call is ambiguous.